# What should be done if user edit their POSTs with junk data

Tags: discussion, support

Consider the recent questions asked by this [user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/26340/slpcc63). example this [POST](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/110115/25879). The user is editing their own posts with junk data (testtest).

So what should be done to this user and POSTS?

Can I rollback those POSTS? or Need to flag it for moderator attention?

It seems the user feels that is a confidential data.

Comment: I think [Letharion](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1625/letharion) rolled back those posts. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, if people are vandalising their (or anyone else's) posts, please roll back the changes.

If it's an isolated incident I wouldn't bother flagging for mod attention, but if you've seen it happen more than once with the same user, then please flag one of their posts so we can have a look

If a user has mistakenly included confidential info in a post, they need to be encouraged to get in touch with a moderator, so we can pass on a request to scrub that info from the database to the right people.

Comment: It was done on three posts, and I reverted them all, and flagged one. In this particular case: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/104275/revisions the user does seem to think there's confidential information. For the future, I've commented that they should flag for mod attention. :)

Comment: User violating the rules, may be suspension ?

Comment: i don't think that's warranted here @Bala - it seems the user was just trying to remove sensitive data they'd accidentally added to the question. Might be wrong of course but that's certainly what it looks like from here

Comment: Cheers @Letharion I'll update here if/when it gets sorted

Comment: Thanks @Clive . It's clear.